# VideoCapture is not working

Tags: java, opencv, video-capture, javacv

When I first ran this code, the object I instantiated from the `VideoCapture` class was normally able to capture frames from the camera and display it in the `JFrame`. Later and unexpectedly, when I ran the program again I found that the `JFrame` displays nothing despite the fact that I have not changed in the code.

What could be the reason for that?

```
    vidCap = new VideoCapture();
        vidCap.open(WEBCAM_EXTERNAL);
        Thread.sleep(2000);// wait to initialize the device;

        if (vidCap.isOpened()) {
            camThread.start();
        } else {
            System.out.println("failed to open the Cam");
        }
    } else {
        Log.E(TAG, "main", "objDescExt is null or empty or has no rows");
    }

    private static class ThreadCam implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        camStream();
    }
}

public static void camStream() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    while(vidCap.grab()) {

        grappedMat = new Mat();
        vidCap.retrieve(grappedMat);

        if (!grappedMat.empty()) {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);//wait a bit to decrease the overhead of the work load as it is an intensive operation
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //MatFactory.writeMat(FilePathUtils.newOutputPath("CapturedImg"), grappedMat);//needed when capture a query image
            Mat sceneDescExt = sceneDescriptor(grappedMat);// FeatureDetection+DescriptorExtractor, returns the descriptorExtractor of the scene/train
            if ( (!sceneDescExt.empty()) && (sceneDescExt.rows() != 0) ) {

                Mat outImg = descMatcher(objDescExt, sceneDescExt);//descriptor Matching operation

                if ( (outImg != null) && (!outImg.empty()) ) {

                    BufferedImage buffImg = mat2BufferedImage(outImg);

                    if (buffImg != null) {
                        facePanel.setFace(buffImg);
                        facePanel.repaint();
                    } else {
                        Log.W(TAG, "camStream", "buffImg is null.");
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.W(TAG, "camStream", "outImg is null or empty.");
                }

            } else {
                Log.W(TAG, "camStream", "sceneDescExt is empty or has no rows");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you only repaint **if** your sceneDescriptor found something

Comment: maybe your camera is stuck. Sometimes happens for me if programs crash without releasing the camera properly. Try to open the camera with different software (direct show graphstudio, some chat software or sth).

Comment: It would be better when posting a long code block like this to post something that can paste into an editor and compile - it looks like there is setup code before this snippet that is needed to define a number of variables (e.g. `camThread` I assume is a `ThreadCam` instance; where is `facePanel` defined etc.).